# xargs: command substitution $(...) with pipe doesn't work

Tags: bash, pipe, command-substitution

I'm trying to write short script, and the following command:

```
echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I {} echo {} | sed 's/111/222/g'
```

returns `aaa222 bbb222`, which is what I expect.

I expected the next command:

```
echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I {} echo $(echo {} | sed 's/111/222/g')
```

to return the same, but it returns `aaa111 bbb111`! Why is that?

---

**UPD:** What I'm trying to achieve:

I have many files like `pic30-coff-gcc`, `pic30-coff-ag`, etc, and I need to make a symlink for each file, like `pic30-gcc` -> `pic30-coff-gcc`, etc.

So I wrote this:

```
ls|grep 'coff-'|xargs -I {} ln -s {} $(echo {} | sed 's/coff-//g')
```

It doesn't work: for each file, it reports that file exists. I checked the command like this:

```
ls|grep 'coff-'|xargs -I {} echo "ln -s {} $(echo {} | sed 's/coff-//g')"
```

And yep, the `sed` part doesn't work:

```
ln -s pic30-coff-gcc pic30-coff-gcc
ln -s pic30-coff-gcc-4.0.3 pic30-coff-gcc-4.0.3
...
```

But if I just type

```
echo "ln -s pic30-coff-gcc $(echo pic30-coff-gcc | sed 's/coff-//g')"
```

it works:

```
ln -s pic30-coff-gcc pic30-gcc
```

Then I've written test command with `aaa111`, and it doesn't work too. Still can't understand, why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that all you need is a simple loop:

```
for file in *coff*; do
  ln -s "${file}" "${file/coff-/}"
done
```

Answer (score 32):

The `for` loop answer is exactly what I didn't come here to read. The whole purpose of `xargs` is avoiding this loop. `xargs` might not be the smartest tool for this particular case, but the question was about it.

Here is the solution I ended up with. It's probably not perfect, but works nevertheless :

```
echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo \$(echo {} | sed 's/111/222/g')"
# Outputs aaa222 bbb222
```

You can come up with different variants of the same command :

```
echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo $(echo {} | sed "s/111/222/g")'
echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo \`echo {} | sed 's/111/222/g'\`"
```

The main point here is just to invoke a new shell that will do the command substitution after `xargs` has replaced the `replace-str`(here `{}`) with the right content.

Comment: A better formulation would be `echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I @@ bash -c 'temp="@@"; echo ${temp//111/222}'`

Comment: While correct, the goal here was to have the same command as used by OP.

Answer (score 16):

`$(echo {} | sed 's/111/222/g')` is evaluated before it's passed to `xargs` as parameter. It will return `{}`.

Hence:

```
echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I {} echo $(echo {} | sed 's/111/222/g')
```

is the same as

```
echo "aaa111 bbb111" | xargs -I {} echo {}
```