# Bash.Bad result of command substitution

Tags: bash, sed, find, xargs

I want to replace spaces in filenames. My test directory contains files with spaces:

```
$ ls
'1 2 3.txt'  '4 5.txt'  '6 7 8 9.txt'
```

For example this code works fine:

```
$ printf "$(printf 'spaces in file name.txt' | sed 's/ /_/g')"
spaces_in_file_name.txt
```

I replace spaces on underscore and command substitution return result to double quotes as text. This construction with important substitution is essential in the next case. Such commands as **find** and **xargs** have substitution mark like **{}**(curly braces). Therefore the next command can replace spaces in files.

```
$ find ./ -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs --null -I '{}' mv '{}' "$( printf '{}' | sed 's/ /_/g' )"
mv: './6 7 8 9.txt' and './6 7 8 9.txt' are the same file
mv: './4 5.txt' and './4 5.txt' are the same file
mv: './1 2 3.txt' and './1 2 3.txt' are the same file
```

But I get error. In order to more clearly consider error, instead of **mv** I just use **echo**(or **printf**):

```
$ find ./ -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs --null -I '{}' echo "$( printf '{}' | sed 's/ /_/g' )"
./6 7 8 9.txt
./4 5.txt
./1 2 3.txt
```

As we can see, spaces were not replaced on underscore. But without command substitution, the replacing will be correct:

```
$ find ./ -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs --null -I '{}' printf '{}\n' | sed 's/ /_/g'
./6_7_8_9.txt
./4_5.txt
./1_2_3.txt
```

So the fact of the command substitution **with curly braces** is corrupt the result(because in the first command was correct result), but without command substitution the result is correct. But why???

Comment: There's an unsatisfying duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589438/xargs-command-substitution-with-pipe-doesnt-work/22589627), and a cross-site answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1217376/why-doesnt-command-substitution-work-inside-find) which is about 'find' more than xargs, but explains the problem properly

Answer (score 1):

Your command substitution is run *before* `find` and you're executing

```
mv '{}' "{}"
```

You could change the `find` command to match `.txt` files with at least one space character and use `-exec` and a small bash script to rename the files:

```
find . -type f -name "* *.txt" -exec bash -c '
  for file; do
    fname=${file##*/}
    mv -i "$file" "${file%/*}/${fname// /_}"
  done
' bash {} +
```

- `${file##*/}` remove the parent directories (longest prefix pattern `*/`) and leaves the filename (like the `basename` command)
- `${file%/*}` removes the filename (shortest suffix pattern `/*`) and leaves the parent directories (like the `dirname` command)
- `${fname// /_}` replaces all spaces with underscores

Comment: i can see any value of using `find` you can mv the file to `"${file// /_}"`

Comment: The value of `find` is that it searches in all subdirectories and using the pattern `* *.txt` only files containing (at least) one space character are renamed. Your answer makes sense if only one directory is processed.

Answer (score 0):

it's quite fast and simple with loop just replace `absolute_path` with your path :

```
for f in absolute_path/*.txt; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}";done
```

The `${f// /_}` part utilizes bash's parameter expansion mechanism to replace a pattern within a parameter with supplied string.